# How to map two existing item data from Woocommerce and Quickbooks correctly?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, quickbooks

I am looking at the possibilities of integrating quick book desktop version with an ecommerce site that is powered woocommerce wordpress. The question is how to map two existing item data from Woocommerce and Quickbooks correctly? I will be using webconnector for quickbook. Thanks for any input in the right direction.

Comment: Which data? I mean, most if it should be pretty clear, right? The COMPANY NAME field in WooCommerce goes to the COMPANY NAME field in QuickBooks. Is there a specific issue or question here, or?

Comment: In my scenario there are already existing product data in both databases with different ids. So the question is about how to tell the systems that which id in woocommerce corresponds to which id in quickbook?

Comment: OK, so in your WooCommerce database, store the ID of the thing it corresponds to in QuickBooks...